# Como trasformar un numero decimal a binario en typeScript

Tags: typescript

Hola Como podría trasformar un numero decimal a binario en typeScript con ayuda de la recursividad? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: serías tan amable por favor de añadir lo que haz intentado

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es almacenar en una variable el valor que deseas convertir y luego llamar al método toString con un parametros "2". 
Ejemplo

```
let n = 254;
let j = n.toString(2); 
alert(j);
```

[image: Resultado de alert(n.toString(2));]

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no se debe contestar las preguntas que no demuestren que se haya intentado algo. Ademas, esta pidiendo hacerlo recursivamente (tal vez es una tarea para el colegio?)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.